# Run a remote PowerShell from Datto RMM

Tags: powershell

How can I run `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\TestFolder\Test.exe"` on remote computer from a Datto RMM console with PowerShell?

This command works locally but not from RMM,

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\TestFolder\Test.exe"
```

Comment: That would be Datto RMM

Comment: Then you probably want to consult [Datto's documentation](https://rmm.datto.com/help/en/Content/4WEBPORTAL/Components/Scripting.htm) :)

Comment: Thank you, been there, did not find what I need.

Comment: Use PowerShell remoting to run [remote commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.4).

Answer (score 0):

Provided the file is already present on the endpoint locally, you'd need to invoke the file using a PowerShell Component. You could also run it using the Agent Browser's CMD or PowerShell functions or Web Remote, but all of these have the same caveat that the executable would be run as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and, as such, invisible to anyone sat in front of the device. The only way around this would be to run the Component invoking the file as a Scheduled Job set to run as the logged-in user.